# Android image fetching

Tags: android

What is the simplest way to fetch an image from a url in an android program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using an [AsyncTask](http://file:///C:/android/sdk/docs/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. I originally used [URL.openStream](http://file:///C:/android/sdk/docs/reference/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29), but it has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986767/is-url-openstream-harmful).

```
class DownloadThread extends AsyncTask<URL,Integer,List<Bitmap>>{
 protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(URL... urls){
  InputStream rawIn=null;
  BufferedInputStream bufIn=null;
  HttpURLConnection conn=null;
  try{
   List<Bitmap> out=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
   for(int i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
    URL url=urls[i];
    url = new URL("http://mysite/myimage.png");
    conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
    if(!String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()).startsWith('2'))
      throw new IOException("Incorrect response code "+conn.getResponseCode()+" Message: " +getResponseMessage());
    rawIn=conn.getInputStream();
    bufIn=new BufferedInputStream();
    Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    out.add(b);
    publishProgress(i);//Remove this line if you don't want to use AsyncTask
  }
    return out;
  }catch(IOException e){
    Log.w("networking","Downloading image failed");//Log is an Android specific class
    return null;
  }
  finally{
   try {
     if(rawIn!=null)rawIn.close();
     if(bufIn!=null)bufIn.close();         
     if(conn!=null)conn.disconnect();
   }catch (IOException e) {
     Log.w("networking","Closing stream failed");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Closing the stream/connection and exception handling is difficult in this case. According to [Sun Documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/) you should only need to close the outermost stream, however [it appears to be more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java). However, I am closing the inner most stream first to ensure it is closed if we can't close the `BufferedInputStream`.

We close in a finally so that an exception doesn't prevent them being closed. We account for the possibility of the streams will being `null` if an exception prevented them from being initialised. If we have an exception during closing, we simply log and ignore this. Even this might not work properly if a runtime error occurs .

You can use the `AsyncTask` class as follows. Start an animation in `onPreExecute`. Update the progress in `onProgressUpdate`. `onPostExecute` should handle the actual images. Use `onCancel` to allow the user to cancel the operation. Start it with `AsyncTask.execute`.

It is worth noting that the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java&d=3) and the license allow us to use the class in non-Android projects.

Answer (score 3):

You do it many ways but the simplist way I can think of would be something like this:

```
Bitmap IMG;
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
    try {
        /* Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it. */ 
        URL aURL = new URL("YOUR URL"); 
    URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
    conn.connect(); 
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
    /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */ 
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
    /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */ 
    IMG = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
    bis.close(); 
    is.close(); 

    // ...send message to handler to populate view.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(DEB, "Remtoe Image Exception", e);

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
} finally {
}
}
};

t.start();
```

And then add a handler to your code:

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case 0:
            (YOUR IMAGE VIEW).setImageBitmap(IMG);
            break;
        case 1:
            onFail();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

By starting a thread and adding a handler you are able to load the images without locking up the UI during download.

Comment: I actually forgot to close my streams in my original code. You really should close your streams in the finally block though