# Button contains text & image from the Internet [android]

Tags: android, button, bitmap

how could i get an image and a text from the Internet and made a button for my android application dynamically?And draw them in th position i want.
 i.e by Java code

thinks

Comment: 1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909280/android-image-fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the image and the text, then:

```
button.setText(downloadedText);
button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

You'll have to create a Drawable from the image, which you can probably do using `Drawable#createFromStream`.

Drawing the button in the position you want is no different from a normal button. Just declare it in your XML (possible set to Visibility.GONE at first), get a reference to it using `View.findViewById` and then do the above operations on it.