# specify the postion of a text & and an image in a botton [android]

Tags: android, image, button

i asked the question about haw to create a button by a text & an image

[Button contains text & image from the Internet [android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828906/button-contains-text-image-from-the-internet-android)

it was very helpful.But, the problem is :
i want a button contains the image & under it the text (not as background)
am looking how to add this image as the text and specify their place??

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating `LayerDrawable` with two layers: transparent (size of the button) and your image on top and set it as background. Then add text as a caption and use `gravity = bottom` to position it.