# How to Define Google Endpoints API File Download Message Endpoint

Tags: python, google-app-engine, response, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

All the examples I can find on google endpoint api (e.g., tic-tac-toe sample)  show strings, integers, enums, etc fields. None of the examples say anything about how to specify document (e.g., image or zip files) uploads or downloads using the API. Is this not possible?

If this is possible, can anyone share a code snippet on how to define google endpoint api on the server to allow downloads and uploads of files? For example, is there a way to set HTTPResponse headers to specify that an endpoint response will serve a zip file? How do we include the zip file in the response?

An example with python or php would be appreciated. If anyone from the endpoints-proto-datastore team is watching this discussion, please say whether or not file downloads are supported in endpoints at the moment. We hate to waste our time trying to figure this out if it is simply impossible. Thanks.

We are seeking a complete example for upload and download. We need to store the key for the uploaded file in our database during upload and retrieve it for download. The client app sends a token that the API needs to use to figure out what file to download. Hence, we would need to store the blob key generated during the upload process in our database. Our database would have the mapping between the token and the blob file's key.

```
class BlobDataFile(models.Model):
   data_code       = models.CharField(max_length=10) # Key used by client app to request file
   blob_key        = models.CharField()
```

By the way, our app is written in Django 1.7 with a mysql (modeled with models.Model) database. It is infuriating that all the examples for Google App Engine upload I can find is written for a standalone webapp Handlers (no urls.py/views.py solutions could be found anywhere). Hence, building a standalone uploader is as much of a challenge as writing the API code. If your solution has full urls.py/views.py example for uploading files and saving the blob_key in our BlobDataFile, it would be good enough for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f you use the blobstore use the [get_serving_url](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) function to read the images from url in the client, or use the [messages.ByteField](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/messages/fieldclasses) in the ResourceContainer and serialize the image with base64.b64decode

```
#the returned class
class Img(messages.Message):
     message = messages.BytesField (1)

#The api class
@endpoints.api(name='helloImg', version='v1')
class HelloImgApi(remote.Service):

ID_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        id=messages.StringField(1, variant=messages.Variant.STRING))

@endpoints.method(ID_RESOURCE, Img,
                  path='serveimage/{id}', http_method='GET', #ID is the blobstore key
                  name='greetings.getImage')
def image_get(self, request):
    try:
        blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
        value = blob_reader.read()

        return Img(message=value)
    except:
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException('image %s not found.' %
                                          (request.id,))        

APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([HelloImgApi])
```

And this is the response (save it in the client with the proper format)

```
{
  "message": "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"
}
```

in the client you can do this (in python for continuity)

```
import base64

myFile = open("mock.jpg", "wb")
img = base64.b64decode(value)  #value is the returned string
myFile.write(img)
myFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show code example for each of the scenarios (i.e., serializing server documents for downloads and reading client uploads)?

Comment: @Sunny to serve the image with  get_serving_url see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15562771/142904

Comment: This is lot closer to what I am seeking. However, your solution does not include any upload code. Hence, I am not able to test your download solution to see if it works. By the way, we are using mysql (defined db with models.Model) database for our non-blob data. We need to store the key for the uploaded file in our database during upload and retrieve it for download. The client app sends a token that the API needs to use to figure out what file to download. Our database would have the mapping between the token and the blob file's key.

Comment: For what it is worth, the following link is a more complete example.http://darrenoneill.co.uk/post/django-api-gae-cloud-endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting the image to base64 string and send it as an argument of your request on the client side?

So you will be able to do that on the server side :

```
#strArg is the Base64 string sent from the client
img = base64.b64decode(strArg)
filename = 'someFileName.jpg' 
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(img)
#then you can save the file to your BlobStore
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the code snippet you posted. What is strArg? How is the code snippet related to Endpoint, message or model definitions?

Comment: Pintouch, please clarify your answer.

Comment: I edited my question, so strArg is just a required argument in your request that represent your image in Base64 format.

Comment: This example makes absolutely no sense. Three lines of code. Really? This is not very helpful and should be down-voted.

Comment: In your question you're not asking "How to create a EndPoint method", so I pretend that you know that and I just give the implementation to convert a Base64 String to an Image File. How to create Endpoints method in Python, check the "Defining an API Method" section : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#defining_an_api_method_endpointsmethod

Comment: It seems you read only the title of the post. The body of our question states that we are looking for a complete upload/download solution.